# How to reverse the accordion-button content in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, alignment, arabic, bootstrap-5

I'm coding a website in Arabic language content.
Problem: The content of the accordion-button should be reversed (the question in the right,the down arrow in the left).
How can I solve it?

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x library -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="questions">
  <!--Begining of the item-->
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#quest_1">
            السؤال الأول
          </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="quest_1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#questions">
      <div class="accordion-body text-end">
        الإجابة على السؤال الأول
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Ending of the item-->
</div>
```

Comment: already tried `dir="rtl"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply add `dir="rtl"` (direction: Right-To-Left) to the button. If you want to change the whole website to an "arabic layout" you could also add it to the `<html>` tag directly: `<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">`

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x library -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">



<!-- Body -->
<div class="accordion accordion-flush" id="questions">
  <!--Begining of the item-->
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingOne">
      <button dir="rtl" class="accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#quest_1">
            السؤال الأول
          </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="quest_1" class="accordion-collapse collapse" data-bs-parent="#questions">
      <div class="accordion-body text-end">
        الإجابة على السؤال الأول
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Ending of the item-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add this custom css roles

```
.accordion-button::after{
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
```

if you are using both rtl and ltr , use a condition